# $f(x)= x^3+3x+2$. If $g(x)= f^{-1}(x)$, what is $g'(2)$?

Tags: calculus

How do you find the inverse of $f(x)$ and subsequently the derivative of the inverse? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint:  you don't need to find an explicit form for the inverse.  Apply the chain rule to both sides of $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually no need to find an explicit expression for the inverse of f(x). If we use the defining property of the inverse function $f^{-1}$, which is that 
$$f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$$
whenever f is invertible, then we may take the derivative of both sides of this equation, using the chain rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(f(x))) = \frac{d}{dx}(x)$$
$$\frac{df^{-1}}{dx}(f(x))\cdot\frac{df}{dx}(x) = 1$$
Therefore, whenever $\frac{df}{dx}(x)\neq 0$, we have:
$$\frac{df^{-1}}{dx}(f(x)) = \left(\frac{df}{dx}(x)\right)^{-1}$$
In a slightly better notation,
$$(f^{-1})'(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}$$
In English, the derivative of $f^{-1}$ at the input value $f(x)$ is the same as the multiplicative inverse (reciprocal) of the derivative of $f$ at the input value $x$.

So, to address your problem, you want to find the derivative of $f^{-1}$ at the input value of $f(x) = 2$ (the input values of $f^{-1}$ are output values of $f$). So to use our equation, we need only find out what value of $x$ solves the equation $f(x) = 2$, since we need to find $f'(x)$ at that value and take its reciprocal.

If $2 = x^3 + 3x + 2$, then $0 = x^3 + 3x$. Factoring the right side tells us that $0 = x(x^2 + 3)$, which can only occur if $x = 0$, since $x^2 + 3$ can never be 0. So the value of $x$ we need to use in our equation is 0. That leads us to 
$$(f^{-1})'(2) = (f^{-1})(f(0)) = \frac{1}{f'(0)}$$
Since $f'(x) = 3x^2 + 3$, we have $f'(0) = 3$. So
$$(f^{-1})'(2) = \frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a general formula for the derivative of the inverse:
$$g'(x)=\frac1{f'\bigl(g(x)\bigr)},\quad\text{provided}\enspace f'\bigl(g(x)\bigr)\ne 0. $$
Here, obviously, $x^3+3x+2=2\iff x(x^2+3)=0\iff x=0$, hence
$$g'(2)=\frac1{3(x^2+1)}\Bigg\vert_{x=0}=\frac13.$$